# Is it efficient to have 85620 object of a class?

Tags: c++

I am writing a program which reads from a file and processes the data in the file. Each line in the file is an entity. There are 85620 lines in the file. Is it efficient to define a class of the entity and have 85620 instances of that class?

Comment: It depends on the structure of the class.

Comment: 85620 member variables would be a little extreme.

Comment: I don't think this question can be answered in its current form. Why would it not be efficient? What other method would you be comparing it to? What do you mean by efficiency (time, space, both)? etc

Comment: I wondered if 85620 is large number for a class...

Comment: @Bernard Can I transport those 5 boxes with my car? Depends if they are filled with feathers or depleted uranium and what kind of car we are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, especially if you're storing them in a memory-efficient container like `std::vector` (hint: reserve some space up front if you know you always need at least a thousand or so).

Answer (score 2):

Depends a bit on the class. But in general, 80k objects is a non-concern.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on a lot of factor, and the target software/hardware requirements.
On modern computer with 8GB+ memory, 80k object with even 1K each would not be a big deal, however it may be an issue on mobile phone or embedded systems.

Also note that if you are doing single pass processing and do not need the data afterward, there is no reason to store them.